# Why does DataContractJsonSerializer skip deserializing some properties?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

We ran into a weird problem recently where two properties from a JSON object weren't being deserialized.

Given this class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Hotel
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  .... other properties

  [DataMember]
  public string double? Latitude { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string double? Longitude { get; set; }

  .... other properties
}
```

and a matching JSON string:

```
{
  "Address":"123 Maple Avenue",
  "Name":"My Awesome Hotel",
  "Phone":"+15550001212",
  "PostalCode":"",
  "Province":"ON",
  "latitude":45.421530,
  "longitude":-75.697193
}
```

Neither the `latitude` nor `longitude` properties were being set.

Here's the deserialization code:

```
public static object Deserialize(Type concreteType, string serialized)
{
   var jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialized);
   using (var jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader
                           (jsonBytes, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
   {
      var dcjs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(concreteType);
      return dcjs.ReadObject(jsonReader);
   }
}
```

What was extremely puzzling is that other classes with the same `latitutde`/`longitude` properties *were* being deserialized correctly. To be clear: there were other classes deserializing JSON strings where the names in the JSON were lower-case and the C# properties were in PascalCase.

(Interestingly enough, JSON.Net was able to deserialize this without any problem)

So what was happening with `DataContractJsonSerializer` and this particular string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, `DataContractJsonSerializer` expects all the properties in the JSON string to be in alphabetical order if they're not capitalized. Changing the data to

```
{
  "Address":"123 Maple Avenue",
  "latitude":45.421530,
  "longitude":-75.697193
  "Name":"My Awesome Hotel",
  "Phone":"+15550001212",
  "PostalCode":"",
  "Province":"ON",
}
```

made the object deserialize perfectly.

(Leaving the properties in the same order and capitalizing the 'L' also worked, as expected)

Comment: Would you care to explain the -1? I've tested the scenario thoroughly and provided a solution..

Answer (score 2):

latitute and longitude are lower case in your JSON but the properties of the object have capital L's

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, we were happily deserializing other classes where the JSON string had lower-case lat/long. The other classes also used PascalCase for the property names. I've updated the question to make this more clear.